When is the JDBC connection pool created
I am creating a oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource datasource bean using jdbc
PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
//other pds properties
pds.setSQLForValidateConnection("select 1 from dual");
//other settings
poolDataSource.setPoolDataSource(pds);

In the app initialization, the bean is created.
But when I am running the first database query after this, it is taking a longer time. In the database I can see the connections are created, only after that first sql query.
Why the connection pool is not created on select 1 from dual

The validation query is run on a connection before it used, not when the pool is created. As the name implies, the validation query checks that the connection is still healthy.
But you're confusing the creation of the pool and the creation of connections held by the pool. The connection pool is created in the code you show in your question, but depending on your settings, connections may not be created until you get a connection from the pool for the first time.

Creating the Pooldatasource Bean does not create and start the pool. The pool will be created and started when you request the connection for the first time for your query execution. The pool start happens lazily and that's why it takes longer time for your first execution.

The pool is created immediately, but will be initially empty (might depend on the configuration though). When the first connection is requested, then the connection will actually be established, but the pool already exists at that time.

When I tried last time it did behave strange. Even if minimal amount of connections was configured, the pool "started" after the 1st connection was requested. But maybe UCP connection pool just need some time to "warm up".
